# Text pipe not working in powershell

Tags: powershell

As asked by someone else here: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/issues/322...

The command `node somescript.js | bunyan` (where `somescript.js` writes utf8 text to stdout and `bunyan` consumes stdin) produces no output when run on powershell, but works fine with cmd.exe.

I know PS pipes are based on objects, but I can't find anything describing why plain text wouldn't work or how to make it work. Is there a way to run this pair of commands with PS?

Comment: try this: `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;node somescript.js | bunyan`

Comment: @SimonS still no output :(